# Write in stacktrace

Tags: c#, exception, stack-trace

Can I throw some text in the stack trace?

My application already has a grip on the exceptions thrown. But would like to have some more information on some methods (parameters).

The idea was to do something like

```
StackTrace.Insert (0, "argument:" + test);
```

I know this is not cool, but is it possible?

Comment: Would this be sufficient? `throw new InvalidOperationException("argument1:" + test + ", argument2:" + test2);`

Comment: but it will stop my method, no?

Comment: Could the solution be to create the exception, and put the parameters in the [Data dictionary property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data(v=vs.100).aspx)? (Then throw the exception...)

Comment: Do you have any logging infrastructure in your application?

Comment: Edited: There's nothing WPF specific here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create the exception, and put the parameters in the [Data dictionary property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wyfbc48.aspx). Then throw the exception...

Comment: Made it an answer since my comment was voted useful, and I think it's more of an answer than a comment.

Comment: Very nice. The key is to throw this newly created exception otherwise the StackTrace will not be populated.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to @erikH's excellent answer:

In addition to using the `Data` property, if you need additional data available up the exception chain, you can do so by means of a custom exception. In addition to the meta-information that a custom type can provide (a `CommunicationException` might mean a problem with I/O, an `InvalidStateException` might mean the program encountered an invalid state, and so forth) you can add additional information to the exception in the form of custom fields. Custom fields are especially useful when you need type safety that the `Data` property doesn't provide.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, the stack trace is an output of the active stack frames at the current execution point in a program, generally accessed via an Exception.

@David Yaw gave you the correct way to add additional information to a stack trace, as it bubbles up the exception stack.  To rephrase, you should only be adding your custom data to the stack trace, when it is the result of an exception.

Either create some centrally accessible List collection to store logging data in, or use proper try/catch with exception bubbling as David recommended.

for example.

```
try
{
  doSomethingThatMightFailAndThrowAnException();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  throw new Exception("Here is some custom data to add to the trace...",ex);
  // Notice adding the ex as the second parameter preserves the original exception trace
}
```